# The max function Null vs. Nullif(1, 1) as arguments in db2

Tags: sql, function, null, db2, max

I was testing out the db2 max function to see if it picks NULL as the maximum of a list of nulls.

So I ran this query:

```
SELECT max (a.colname)
FROM (SELECT null AS colname FROM <replace with any small table name>) a
```

This, however, gave this error message:

```
DB2 Database Error: ERROR [428F5] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0245N  The invocation of routine "MAX" is ambiguous. The argument in position "1" does not have a best fit.  SQLSTATE=428F5
```

I was able to test what I was set to do by replacing `null` with `nullif(1,1)` and it, indeed, returns `null` as the maximum value in a list of `null` values.

According to this [page](http://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-245_sqlstate_428F5.html), the sql state means that the function max has different, say implementations or overloads, that could handle the argument `a.colname`, and hence the error.

I am not sure where I can find more about the implementation of the max function in db2, as the [IBM page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref/fmax.htm) does not say anything about that.

Any idea on how null  and nullif differ in their type, espicially in the context of the max function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select a datatype for that column, try this:

```
SELECT max (a.colname)
FROM (SELECT CAST(null AS INT) AS colname FROM <replace with any small table name>) a
```

In your first query, the `MAX` doesn't know the datatype for that column. In your second query, its assigning a datatype based on the input (in this case, a 1), so it may be saying that is an `INT`, so it can compute the `MAX`.